# React native flexbox: set grow factor to generic presentational component

Tags: react-native, flexbox, components

In a *React* scenario where a generic *App* container holds a presentational component called *Row*, how do we instruct the latter to be twice-as-big as its sibling *View* using *flexbox*?

```
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <View style={{flex: 1}} />
        <Row style={{flex: 2}} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This is how Row component looks like, which is using again flexbox on the parent element to utilize all the space available:

```
export default function Row(props: Props){
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      //some more children flex items
    </View>
  )
};
```

The above example won't give the expected result, as the *flex* style passed to *Row* element from *App* component ({flex: 2}) is overwritten by the style assigned from within the presentational component itself.

**What is best practice to make a *flex* presentational component whose flex grow factor is set by its container component?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your flexbox understanding is correct, the issue is that you didn't pass `{{flex: 2}}` to `Row` component correctly.

`<Row style={{flex: 2}} />` style prop in this line is just a prop passed to your `Row` component that you didn't use so it's not applied.

Try the following

```
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <View style={{flex: 1}} />
        <Row style={{flex: 2}} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}


export default function Row(props: Props){
  const { style } = props;
  return (
    <View style={[{backgroundColor: 'green'}, style]}>
      //some more children flex items
    </View>
  )
};
```

As you can see in `Row` component style props is passed to the `View` i added the `backgroundColor: green` as an example of the component own style, then `style` props is the style coming from component props, this should work.

To recap `style` prop can be passed only to `react-native` components not to your custom components, to be able to use `style` as in your example, you just need to pass that style to react-native `View` by yourself as in the code above.

Comment: is this what you recommend? or prefer for example setting flex="2" as a prop on its own on the element?

Comment: No since this is a style it is better to pass style object ... because you might need to add more style later ... I personally believe that passing style object is better as in your example, unless Row is a layout specific component that you want to customize that way